# how can i attach a t-post to my well casing to allow an outlet to be mounted?

Tags: electrical, well

There is no ability to drive the post into the ground as there are close gas, water and power lines.  Hose clamps don't seem to be strong enough, nor wire ties.

I could consider a 'doghouse' right on top of the well casing but that invites animal and gas buildup issues.

Comment: Are  gas, water and power lines right up against the well casing? "*gas buildup issues*" ??

Comment: I was just thinking any gas coming out of the well would pool in the doghouse.  Power lines come up from ground right at well casing.  Propane tank is behind well, close enough i dont want to pound t-posts in.

Comment: You appear to be overcomplicating this. If your well produces flammable gas (Fracking region?) that will be methane and it will be easily removed by screened vents, as it is lighter than air. A tightly built wellhouse with properly screened vents will also keep out animals. Unless your propane tank is leaking into the well (and that should be fixed) nothing will "pool".  You or your propane tank installer should know exactly where the buried propane line is located.

Comment: I was just thinking some gas comes out of the well no matter what.  There are no known issues with the well or propane tank.  It is not in a fracking region.  So one option is build a wellhouse over the well and mount the box on or in that.  thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at U-bolts?  If the casing's too big for U-bolts into the box, you can always throw a couple pieces of uni-strut at it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy with strut channel such as Unistrut brand.

[image: strut channel]

You can attach the strut to the casing with strut pipe clamps.  You can get these in just about whatever size you'd need.

[image: strut pipe clamp]

These clamp the strut perpendicular to the pipe.

[image: strut and pipe]

With two pieces of strut clamped perpendicular to the casing, spaced the same distance of the mounting holes on the box, you have a very solid structure to attach to.  You can then use fender washers inside the channel with nuts and bolts to secure the box to the strut.

That will be about bomb proof.  It might seem like overkill, but I agree that even heavy duty hose clamp style clamps don't really do it, and this is quick and easy.

Alternately you may be able to use U-bolts to strap the strut to the pipe, depending on the size of the pipe, but I prefer strut pipe clamps.  I think you get a secure attachment without stressing the wall of the pipe as much as the U-bolt does.